# Can't load windows after poweroutage in hibernation

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

First of all I realise my problem is like a few others on here but I have tried everything on the other questions and nothing worked.

So the problem is that my computer gets stuck on load screen, the windows 7 logo comes up and does the animation. about 30 seconds later I hear the windows login sound (used to take only a few seconds)

What happened is that I had my computer in hibernate mode and then a power outage occured.

What I've tried:

- Safe mode into reboot
- Safe mode to remove anti virus
- start in 'no gui mode' <- this removed the windows logo but it didn't
  get replaced with anything, just black screen
- startup repair
- diskcheck
- system restore <- gives an error saying it isn't working properly and
  won't let me continue
- Full system scan with AVG and Combofix
- Reset CMOS

Nothing of the above helped, any ideas?

edit: In no gui mode it shows a series of small horizontal blue-ish lines at the top of the screen
edit 2: I've found out that the problem is in the file that saves your ram onto your hdd. Problem is that I can't edit hibernation or the file from safe mode, which is the only mode i can get the computer to run in.

when I try powercfg -H off it gives me the following error

Hibernation failed with the following error: The request is not supported. The following items are preventing hibernation on this system. VgaSave. An internal system component has disabled hibernation

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: Try resetting the cmos with the jumper labeled clear CMOS, or, unplug the computer, plug in something that charges off USB and hold the power button down for a few mins to drain the CMOS battery, this happened to me once about a month ago, first time I'd seen it, except I had it worse, where it wouldn't even post till I cleared the CMOS and was able to tell it was supposed to be in sleep mode.

Comment: Forgot to add that one, I have also tried resetting the cmos. I did this by pulling the battery out, though.